# Python rstrip() doesn't work

Tags: python, csv

So I have a script ([Python: Openpyxl outputs "None" for empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464804/python-openpyxl-outputs-none-for-empty-cells/40465801)) that converts an XLSX file to a CSV file.

One of the cells is on multiple lines and contains no double quotes. When I run rstrip() it still remains on multiple lines

Any ideas?

```
for rownum in sh.iter_rows():
                values = [("" if cell.value is None else unicode(cell.value).encode('ascii','ignore').rstrip()) 
                    for cell in rownum]
                wr.writerow(values)
```

The first line in the CSV file is:

```
"S. No","Summary","Question","Answer","Keywords","Product","Category","Access Level (Everyone, Help, Platinum)","Status 
Public (Customer facing)
Private (Internal only)"
```

How do I get the last cell

Comment: rstrip is working perfectly. It is supposed to remove default whitespace characters from the end of a string not remove new lines.

Comment: You could try .replace('\n','') to remove the new lines.

Answer (score 3):

rstrip() will only remove the whitespace at the end of the string not the newlines in the middle of the strings.
Do the following instead:
lets say the variable values contains your string, then:

```
values = ' '.join(values.strip().split('\n'))
```